# how to render a _form from another view folder in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In **carts/_form**:

```
 <% for item in @cart.line_items %>             
 <%= item.quantity %> &times;<%= item.menu.menu_item_name %>
 <%= item.quantity*item.menu.price%>    
 <% end %>
```

in menus/index:

```
 <%= render partial: 'carts/form'%>
```

I want to show the `_form` on `index` page.

Comment: if you save your form in a partials folder in the views directory, you can render a partial stored there anywhere in your app.  I'm pretty sure you can do render "partials/_form"  You don't need to save partials to a view directory that pertains to a model.

Comment: without creating partials folder, i want to only _form from carts folder to be rendered.

Comment: save the part of the code that you want as its own partial and then render it

Answer (score 2):

The point of partials is to have them as chunks of code that can be used anywhere in your app.  Unless I misunderstand your question, might I suggest creating the following directory structure:

```
app
|-views
   |-cart(or wherever your form currently is)
   |-partials
      |-_partialYouWantToUse.html.erb
```

This way you can render it using

```
<%= render "partials/partialYouWantToUse" %>
```

ANYWHERE you want in your app.

*Note you do not use an underscore _ when you are rendering the partial, you only save it with one.*

**edit** as a result of your comment:

You can render a partial from any folder, as long as it's relative to the view folder.
so:
    <%= render "WhateverFolder/evenAnotherFolder/_whateverpartial" %>

As long as whateverFolder is a direct decendent of views.

The partial or layout folder is a rails convention, and helps for people who are looking through your code. It keeps things organized.

Comment: is there any other way without creating a partials folder.i.e using jquery

Comment: You may not need to create a partials folder, but you can render the partial by calling using render with the directory that it is contained in I think. see my edit

Comment: <%= render "carts/partials/partialYouWantToUse" %> while using this code in menus/index.html.erb i am getting no error but the problem is that the page gets redirected to carts/show.It should't be redirected.

Comment: Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb wi
thin rescues/layout (42.0ms)

Answer (score 0):

In `carts/_form.html.erb` :

```
 <% for item in @cart.line_items %>             
 <%= item.quantity %> &times;<%= item.menu.menu_item_name %>
 <%= item.quantity*item.menu.price%>    
 <% end %>
```

to use in `_form.html.erb` in any other `*.html.erb` put line

```
<%= render "carts/form" %>
```

in `*.html.erb` documents inside carts catalog, you can write simple :

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

because it's look for `_form.html.erb` in present catalog